# Mysql modify UNSIGNED attribute to specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a issue adding `unsigned` attribute to existing column.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
ALTER TABLE cla_budget MODIFY COLUMN id UNSIGNED;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

**Error:** *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED' at line 1.*

I´ve tried sql modify command alone, result is same error as above:

```
ALTER TABLE cla_budget MODIFY COLUMN id UNSIGNED;
```

Also tried:

```
1. ALTER TABLE `cla_budget` MODIFY COLUMN `id` UNSIGNED;
2. ALTER TABLE `cla_budget` MODIFY COLUMN `id` unsigned;
3. ALTER TABLE `cla_budget` MODIFY `id` unsigned;
...
```

I searched for sollution here, also in mysql manual. I ran queries in **phpMyAdmin**.

**Database server:**

- Server version: 5.7.15-9-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release '9', Revision '9f0fd0a'
- Protocol version: 10
- Mysql 5.7

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: from the documentation: "When you use CHANGE or MODIFY, column_definition must include **the data type** and all attributes that should apply to the new column" (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: @MartinSchneider Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using this query should work.

```
ALTER TABLE cla_budget MODIFY COLUMN cla_budget.id **[DataTypeOfId]** UNSIGNED;
```

You have to specify the datatype of the modified column when using ALTER.

Regards